# mysql deleted /var/lib/mysql my.cnf

Tags: mysql, fedora, yum

i have following problem, I messed around with the mysql files without really understand what they are good for. 
Basically I deleted the databases and the my.cnf. Writing a new my.cnf isn't a problem but I can't restore the databases especially
the schema's. Without them I can't start mysql. I already tried yum -reinstall mysql but that didn't seem to restore those files at all. Can you help me with this problem please?

I am using Fedora 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recreate your `my.cnf`. You'll probably want to at least ensure it's got the following contents:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
```

For a more sensible set of defaults, use the one that comes with the distribution, or find a file called `my-default.cnf` if you're running a recent version. You might have other `.cnf` files to look at for inspiration.

Then, find the `mysql_install_db` script with `locate mysql_install_db` and run it like this (as root):

```
/path/to/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

That will set up a basic default installation with the necessary system databases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer so far. locate mysql_install_db returns /usr/bin/mysql_install_db yet when I try to run it it tells me that there is no such file or directory. ls -a won't show it either.

Comment: Sounds like you deleted it too, since your last `updatedb` (the thing that populates `locate`. You'll need to reinstall completely with `yum install community-mysql-server` (in Fedora 19) and you might also need the `community-mysql` package to get the client.